# Got a CMake errors in CLion in manjaro linux

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, clion, manjaro

Hello stackoverflow community. I downloaded CLion to make c++ programm. I created an c++ executable project and it wanted run/debug configuration from me. Then I chose CMake project and tried to compile simple "Hello World" programm, but I got some CMake errors.

```
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".`  `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
```

I checked clion-environment.txt file in CMake folder

```
ToolSet: 1.0 (local)Options: 

Options:-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++
```

When I try to compile file in command line by g++ all is fine. Have any ideas how to fix it? Here is CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(final)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(final main.cpp)
```

and here is my laptop's system information

- Host: just-r
- Kernel: 5.4.31-1-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 compiler:
- gcc v: 9.3.0
- Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.18.4
- Distro: Manjaro Linux linux 54

Thanks in advice

Comment: Does CMake work when you run it directly (and not under CLion)? Do you have C compiler `cc` on the path? Do you have `make` or `ninja` installed?

Comment: Hello, tnx for reply. When I type cmake or make --version I haven't anything, so I suppose that CLion have them inside.yes, I have gcc in Path

Comment: You definitely need to install cmake independently and tell clion to use it. Else you won’t be able to automate what you are doing later. Once installed try running (outside of the source dir `cd /path/to/build/dir; cmake /path/to/src/dir`. It should behave very similar to clion.

Comment: Ok I will write about result soon

Comment: I builded cmake files in cmd, it works. But same problems by using in CLion. Maby I should integrate it into CLion? but I don't know how.

Comment: Has CLion properly detected your `make` executable? You can check by going to **File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolchains** in CLion, selecting your default toolchain, and checking which `make` executable is used (if any) in the fillable box next to the **Make:** section.

Comment: yes :))))...... thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Has CLion properly detected your make executable? You can check by going to File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolchains in CLion, selecting your default toolchain, and checking which make executable is used (if any) in the fillable box next to the Make: section. – squareskittles